# Bootstrap collapse/accordion on table not working as intended

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, bootstrap-4, razor-pages

I have a bootstrap table with 4 rows. Each of those rows can be clicked, revealing child rows which are unique to each of the four parent rows.

All works fine as long as I collapse a row before un-collapsing another, but if I un-collapse a row and then un-collapse another, only one child row will show inside this newly un-collapsed parent row, even if there are supposed to be more child rows than just the one inside that parent row. Then, if I click on the parent row again, it will show all of the child rows inside that parent row, apart from the one that was just showing.

How do I fix this glitchy behavior? I should be able to click a parent row without collapsing the previous one first. Ideally the previous row would be collapsed automatically upon un-collapsing a new row.

**Razor Page table:**

```
<table id="accordionTable" class="table" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <thead style="color:white;">
        <th>DATABASE</th>
        <th>STATUS</th>
        </thead>

        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.statusList.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="@("#innerTable" + i)">
                <td>@Model.Databases[i]["DATABASE_NAME"].ToString().ToUpper()</td>
                <td @*class="@Model.StatusAll[i]"*@>@Model.StatusAll[i]</td>
            </tr>

            foreach (var number in Model.statusList[i])
            {
                <tbody>
                    <tr @if (number.ToString() == "Running...") { @: style="background-color: #ccffc4;"
                        } else if (number.ToString() == "Scheduled") { @: style="background-color: #d1f3fc;"
                        } else if (number.ToString() == "Failed") { @: style="background-color:#ffe4e4;"
                        }
                        style="cursor:default; background-color: white;" data-parent="#accordionTable" id="@("innerTable" + i)">

                        <td> @number.ToString()</td>
                        <td @if (number == "Running...") { @: class="fas fa-spinner"
                            } else if (number == "Scheduled") { @: class="far fa-clock"
                            } else if (number == "Failed") { @: class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"
                            }>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            }
        }
    </table>
```

Comment: You can try to remove attribute  `data-parent="#accordionTable" ` in the child `tr` tags, then add `class ="collapse"`  in the child tr tags. Like `style="cursor:default; background-color: white;" class="collapse" id="@("innerTable" + i)">
`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Nan Yu above, this is how I fixed it:

You can try to remove `attribute data-parent="#accordionTable"` in the child `tr` tags, then add `class ="collapse"` in the child tr tags. Like `style="cursor:default; background-color: white;" class="collapse" id="@("innerTable" + i)">` – Nan Yu